# Gradle html report per test class

Tags: html, testing, gradle, report

I have a project, were I define some classes to be called in different environments, so I have multiple test tasks, which contain this test. XML reports can be seperated per test task, so I see all results of all runs of this test class, that's fine.

But in the html report, which is automatically generated by gradle, you only see the latest run of the methods of this test class, which overwrites all earlier result. Is there a possibility to configure gradle to use a prefix per test task to have the class unique or to write a seperate index.html for all test tasks?

How do you recommend to handle this situation?

Best regards
Markus

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the `testResultsDirName` and `testReportDirName` [convention properties](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1233C) so for each test run the test results and reports will be located in a separate folder.
This can be done, for example, using a project property, e.g.:

```
if (this.hasProperty("testEnvName")) {
    testResultsDirName = testResultsDirName + "/" + testEnvName
    logger.info('Test results folder for project "' + project.name + '" set to "' + testResultsDir + '"')

    testReportDirName = testReportDirName + "/" + testEnvName
    logger.info('Test report folder for project "' + project.name + '" set to ' + testReportDirName + '"')
}
```

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1233C